# Can I copy and paste guides in Sketch across different artboards?

Tags: sketch-app

I have set up some custom guides on an artboard and would like to use the same set of guides on another artboard, is there a way to copy them across ?

The most obvious way would be to duplicate the artboard, as that would duplicate the guides as well. However, I'm trying to use the guides on a pre-existing artboard to make some changes to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a [plugin](https://github.com/pixelpillow/copy-paste-guides) to do so on Github.

> ## [Copy & Paste Guides](https://github.com/pixelpillow/copy-paste-guides)
>
> For those who rather use guides instead of the layout option in Sketch it's often frustrating to change guides for multiple artboards, especially when working with larger documents. That's why we've created a plugin to easily copy, paste and remove guides from your Sketch artboard(s).

Comment: Hi Enzio, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: Welcome to the site but please know link only answers may get removed and are sometimes treated as spam so please add a little more detail to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Plug-ins FTW

Sketch doesn't have a lot of native functionality around guides due to it's focus on layout grids and smart alignment. As Enzio pointed out, that's why Bohemian gave us access to plug-ins!

In addition to Enzio's handy solution, [**Sketch Utility Belt**](https://github.com/frankko/UtilityBelt) has some great guide features. In this case, it's focused on quickly creating guides based on a layer.

### Complex grids

For complex grids, I prefer to build my own using rectangles like so:

- Group the objects into one layer (set to ~20% opacity).
- Convert the group to a symbol.
- Use the symbol across the doc.
- Edit anywhere, update everywhere.

To quickly flip the visibility of this layer, I use the [Sketch Layer Tools plug-in](https://github.com/hrescak/Sketch-Layer-Tools).